# Does LinkedIn Allow you to Extract Anonymous Company Employee Data?

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api

I'm trying to find out if I can extract anonymous data from LinkedIn companies such as where their employees graduated from, what their skills are, what department they are working in, and what their degree is. Anonymous in the sense that no names, pictures, nor personal information will be collected. I have also attached images on what I want to extract.

[Data what I wish to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8inl.png)
[Data what I wish to extract2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JuL6.png)

I looked into LinkedIn developer and found that they offer APIs on a case to case basis but I am not sure which application would be the most appropriate or if any of them even give me permission to extract any of the data that I am finding.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't write it for you. Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't expecting any code; I was just wondering if anyone knows if LinkedIn would offer access to that data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in knowing the answer to this, I contacted Linkedin Help, but they directed me to Stack Overflow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: We have the same situation, Jaydee. I do hope that someone will be able to help us.